# How to get stream from IP camera on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, ethernet, camera

Im trying to connect my Hikvission camera(model: DS-2CD2043G0-I) to my laptop directly with Ethernet cable. I have connected the cam to POE switch and then connected ehternet cable from the uplink port to my system.

When i assign the default IP address of the cam in wired setting it shows it is connected, but when i try to access the ip for the stream i dont get any. Here is the settings from the wired network tab.[Ip added manually, i also tried with netmask: 255.255.0.0 still no luck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XxzW.png)

[And it shows it is connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojoJn.png)

Here is outputs of ifconfig, arp-scan and route commands!

```
$ ifconfig
enp7s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.95.70  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 169.254.95.255
    inet6 fe80::2e18:dc16:2189:fdb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 98:28:a6:1a:36:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 22  bytes 5011 (5.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 132361  bytes 5632240 (5.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16767  bytes 1328111 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16767  bytes 1328111 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.136  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::b3e9:da18:da0b:fc39  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c0:b6:f9:93:6f:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 52369  bytes 58459180 (58.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22870  bytes 3968202 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ sudo arp-scan --interface=enp7s0f1 --localnet
Interface: enp7s0f1, type: EN10MB, MAC: 98:28:a6:1a:36:0d, IPv4: 169.254.95.70
Starting arp-scan 1.9.7 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)
169.254.95.70   58:50:ed:1b:40:1c   (Unknown)

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.7: 256 hosts scanned in 2.053 seconds (124.70 hosts/sec). 1 responded

$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp7s0f1
169.254.95.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0f1
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

I've tried many solutions but nothings seems to work. Can anyone please help me out. I have no prior experience of networking. Apart from this im new to Linux too. So if there is some blunder i've made kindly point it out and guide me to right directions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is 169.254.95.70 the @ip of the cam? If so, you must choose another one for the pc wired  adapter. Something like 169.254.95.80/16 (it is an APIPA address, thank you M$)

Comment: im verythankful to you brother. it worked after i changed the ip to 169.254.95.80....thankyou soo much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC media player.  Then click "Media" and "Open Network Stream".  You will need to know what the RTSP URL is to connect with.  Search for it online.  If it recognizes ONVIF then you can just hit the IP address directly:

rtsp://169.254.95.70/